# Can a main activity call itself from postExecute method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my android application I call `AsyncTask` for some background process. In `postExecute()` method I want to call Main activity again. I pass context via the constructor of `AsyncTask` or via any setter but I don't know why startActivity() gives null pointer exception.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Response from server: " + result);

    Intent i = new Intent(context1,FOEActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Comment: Try Intent i = new Intent(Activityname.this,FOEActivity.class);

Comment: context is my activity this I have already tried,anyway thanks for you  prompt response

Comment: Why do you want to call MainActivity from MainActivity?

Comment: Post how you create and start your `AsyncTask`

Comment: simply by creating a subclass of AsyncTask and instantiating an object of it from a method

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update the UI?
In your activity you can simply override the AsyncTask onPostExecute method like this:

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(){
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object object)
        {
            //Now you can update the UI here
        }
    };

asyncTask.execute();
```

When the AsyncTask is completed, the onPostExecute method will be called inside your Activity.